# Migrate data from database to json file android

Tags: android, json, android-database

I have a database and I want to export the data from tables to json file in android

My table has column1, column2, and column3
And my json should be

```
tablename: [
   row 1:[
      column1:{"data1"},
      column2:{"data2"},
      column3:{"data3"}
      ],
 row 2:[
      column1:{"data1"},
      column2:{"data2"},
      column3:{"data3"}
      ]
]
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson to serialize/deserialize Java objects: https://github.com/google/gson

Example:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(MY_LIST);
FileOutputStream outputStream;
outputStream = context.openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
outputStream.write(json.getBytes());
outputStream.close();
```

Where `MY_LIST` is a list filled with data from your table. Example of serializable class:

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {
    String field;
    List<MySecondClass> secondList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    static class MySecondClass implements Serializable{
        int id;
        String data;
    }
}
```

If you are using Kotlin you can use https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization